# Solving Differential Equation - Wolfram Alpha vs Mathematica, different results

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, differential-equations, wolframalpha

I'm solving a differential equation in Mathematica. Here is what I'm solving:

```
DSolve[{-(r V[w])+u V'[w]+s V''[w]==-E^(g w)},V[w],w]
```

When I use Wolfram Alpha to solve it, it gives me a nice solution:

```
solve u*V'(w) + s*V''(w) - r * V = -exp(g*w)
V(w) = c_1 e^((w (-sqrt(4 r s+u^2)-u))/(2 s))+c_2 e^((w (sqrt(4 r s+u^2)-u))/(2 s))+e^(g w)/(r-g (g s+u))
```

But when I use Mathematica, the solution is long and ugly:

> {{V[w] -> (2 s (2 E^(((2 g s + u - Sqrt[4 r s + u^2]) w)/(
>              2 s) + ((-u + Sqrt[4 r s + u^2]) w)/(2 s)) g s - 
>            2 E^(((-u - Sqrt[4 r s + u^2]) w)/(
>              2 s) + ((2 g s + u + Sqrt[4 r s + u^2]) w)/(2 s)) g s + 
>            E^(((2 g s + u - Sqrt[4 r s + u^2]) w)/(
>              2 s) + ((-u + Sqrt[4 r s + u^2]) w)/(2 s)) u - 
>            E^(((-u - Sqrt[4 r s + u^2]) w)/(
>              2 s) + ((2 g s + u + Sqrt[4 r s + u^2]) w)/(2 s)) u + 
>            E^(((2 g s + u - Sqrt[4 r s + u^2]) w)/(
>              2 s) + ((-u + Sqrt[4 r s + u^2]) w)/(2 s)) Sqrt[
>             4 r s + u^2] + 
>            E^(((-u - Sqrt[4 r s + u^2]) w)/(
>              2 s) + ((2 g s + u + Sqrt[4 r s + u^2]) w)/(2 s)) Sqrt[
>             4 r s + u^2]))/(Sqrt[
>          4 r s + u^2] (-2 g s - u + Sqrt[4 r s + u^2]) (2 g s + u + 
>            Sqrt[4 r s + u^2])) + 
>       E^(((-u - Sqrt[4 r s + u^2]) w)/(2 s)) C[1] + 
>       E^(((-u + Sqrt[4 r s + u^2]) w)/(2 s)) C[2]}}

Ew!

In general I would like Mathematica to give me a nice solution, the way Wolfram Alpha does. Does anyone know if I am missing and conditions? Or am I doing things wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Simplify[DSolve[{-(r V[w])+u V'[w]+s V''[w]==-E^(g w)},V[w],w]]`

Simplify is your friend

Comment: Right, of course, thanks! For some reason it isn't simplifying all the way. Maybe Mathematica needs some conditions that I'm leaving out. Edit: Or maybe this IS what Mathematica considers "simplified all the way".